# association in mybatis

Tags: associations, mybatis

I meet some problems in mybatis. This is my configuration:

PostMapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="com.king.model.PostMapper">
    <select id="selectById" parameterType="int" resultMap="postMap">
        select * from posts where id = #{id}
    </select>
    <select id="selectAll" resultType="hashmap">
        select * from posts order by created_at desc
    </select>

    <resultMap id="postMap" type="Post">
        <result property="createDate" column="created_at" />
        <result property="updateDate" column="updated_at" />
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

CommentMapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="com.king.model.CommentMapper">
    <select id="selectById" parameterType="int" resultMap="commentMap">
        select * from comments where id = #{id} order by id desc
    </select>
    <select id="selectAll" resultMap="commentMap">
        select * from comments
    </select>
    <select id="selectByPost" resultMap="commentMap" parameterType="int">
        select * from comments where post_id=#{id}
    </select>
    <resultMap id="commentMap" type="Comment">
        <result property="createDate" column="created_at" />
        <result property="updateDate" column="updated_at" />
        <association property="post" column="post_id" javaType="Post" select="com.king.model.PostMapper.selectById" />
    </resultMap>
</mapper>


public class Post {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String body;
    private Date createDate;
    private Date updateDate;
    private List<Comment> comments;
}

public class Comment {
    private int id;
    private String commenter;
    private String body;
    private Post post;
    private Date createDate;
    private Date updateDate;
}
```

In CommentDao:

```
public List<Comment> listForPost(Post post) {
    return getSqlSession().selectList("com.king.model.CommentMapper.selectByPost", post.getId());
}
```

Then in my controller,I try to list all the comments for one given post:

```
List<Comment> coms = commentDao.listForPost(post);
post.setComments(coms)
```

And I found the above code will trigger two sql select statement:

```
select * from comments where post_id=? 
select * from posts where id = ?
```

However through mybatis 3 guide,it specify that in this suitation, it will cause the "N+1" problem.

For each selected comment,it will trigger select statement for details(the post).

But here is only two select.

What's going on?

And in mybatis should the relation be set as bidirectional or unidirectional for the one-many or many-many association?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything wrong with that.

I believe your relation is one-to-many since a Comment is related to a single Post, while a single Post can have multiple Comment.

It is correct that your code

```
List<Comment> coms = commentDao.listForPost(post);
```

triggers only two queries. It will execute the query named "CommentMapper.selectByPost" which in turn executes your first query and, because of the association, "PostMapper.selectById" that is your second query. So you are traversing your relation backward and this doesn't trigger the N+1 problem.

The N+1 problem happens when you want to get a list of object, each one of whose has a list of related objects. Example, you want to get the list of Post, and also have their Comment.

This means that you execute a query to get the list of Post (1) and then, for each Post, a query to get the Comment (N) => N + 1

This can be solved, if it is reasonable, executing a single query that return in one shot all the comments, each one with (redundant) informations about its Post. MyBatis, with associations, is able to do what is like a "GROUP BY" statement on that result set, that is associate to each instance of Post, the related Comment.

For this to happen you should call the "PostMapper.selectAll" and put the association to Comment in the Post result map!

Answer (score 0):

MyBatis caches Statements by default during the Session.

As postId doesn't change, `select * from posts where id = ?` will evaluate only once.